# What is the cheapest way to see snow from Singapore?

Tags: budget, sightseeing, singapore, snow

I am from Singapore. What is cheapest holiday trip I can take that I can see snow?

(I understand that snowfall is unpredictable and some good luck is required.)

Comment: Cheapest? Must be http://www.snowcity.com.sg

Comment: What about Japan?

Comment: cheapest way is to go to SnowCity, Singapore :) http://www.snowcity.com.sg/snowcity2/index.php

Comment: @Heng-Cheong Leong: So have you gone?

Comment: No, but saving up and planning to go Taipei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheapest flights to destinations which have snow would be:

- Tiger Airways to Taipei, Taiwan, and then onwards from there.
- Tiger Airways Chennai or Bangalore in India, and then a train up to Himalayas or [Indigo](http://goindigo.in) to New Delhi (this would be closer) and then onwards to the Himalayas.
- AirAsia X to Korea / Japan. These are typically quite expensive compared to the above options.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest:-

- Wait for snowfall in the Australia ski-fields
- Look for an AirAsiaX flight from Singapore to Sydney (via KL) (250 SGD)
- Catch a train from Sydney to Canberra (55 SGB)
- Catch a bus from Canberra to Jyndabyne (via Cooma?)
- Catch the ski-tube up to Mount Perisher
- Sleep in a tent at the caravan park

Comment: I would have assumed it'd be cheaper to go to Taiwan, South Korea or Japan. Prices there are a bit cheaper there than they are in oz, too! (I can't really blame the resort operators though - too much demand, too little supply!)

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Might be, I haven't costed them all but it's a suggestion.  Flight costs are likely to dominate so it probably comes down to that especially if you just want to see snow so you do not need a lift ticket or on-snow accom.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Himalayas. Then, you don't need good luck. What is extra -- you get to see really lofty mountains. There are several destinations in Nepal (e.g., Kathmandu), Bhutan and India (e.g., Sikkim, Darjeeling, Ladakh and Dharmshala).

Comment: 1. In India North Sikkim is best option in Feb/March, 2. Manali is another option in November/December